# Unable to make white background at image container

Tags: php, css, responsive-images

I need help to make white colour inside the border along with black description.

The actual scenario is located here: http://buyersstop.blogspot.in/2016/01/motoe.html

My problem is that if I am applying white background colour a black border is showing around the image.

```css
div.img1 {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
div.img1:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.img1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.responsive {
  padding: 6px 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 32.99999%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.post-body img {
padding: 8px;
background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
border: 1px solid transparent;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-radius: 0px;
}

div.desc {
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFF;
color: #000;
}
```

This should take care of it.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as your answer if this is what you needed :)

Comment: Marked with glad. Border is not showing properly. Image also needs to be true center. Awaiting for your suggestion.

Comment: Please visit the link http://buyersstop.blogspot.in/p/moto-e-2nd-generation-4g-white.html

Comment: buyersstop.css div.img1 {      Remove border: 1px solid #777; and it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I've done some modification on your codes see my update codes. Hope same as you expected.

```css
div.img1 {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
div.img1:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.img1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 6px;
    width: 96%;
    background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.5);
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.responsive {
  padding: 6px 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 32.99999%;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#fff;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img1">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71YgvTPQnKL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```